# how to stretch a video to its full width and height?

Tags: html, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am created video tag in React with tailwindcss this way:

```
<div className='flex items-center gap-x-[4.375rem]'>
        <div className='flex gap-x-[4.375rem] gap-y-[1.875rem] max-w-[48.125rem] flex-wrap'>
            <CreateNumericItems />
        </div>
        <video className='w-[38.125rem] h-[31.875rem]' autoPlay loop src="/video/page1Block2.mp4"></video>
    </div>
```

but it doesn't stretch to full height and width

[image: here is image]
How to fix it?

Comment: Is the video's original resolution `610x510`? If so, why are you setting the width and height to `38.125rem`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the width and height to auto? CSS should automatically scale it up to its original size.

```
<div className='flex items-center gap-x-[4.375rem]'>
    <div className='flex gap-x-[4.375rem] gap-y-[1.875rem] max-w-[48.125rem] flex-wrap'>
        <CreateNumericItems />
    </div>
    <video className='w-auto h-auto' autoPlay loop src="/video/page1Block2.mp4"></video>
</div>
```